# How is max() function working in following code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Can someone please explain to me how is `max()` function working in the following code?

```
strings = ['enyky', 'benyky', 'yely','varennyky']
print(max(strings))
```

`max()` function should return the longest string in following `list`, that is 'varennyky', instead I am getting 'yely' as output.
Can someone please explain me?

Answer (score -1):

It's returning the last item in sort order.

You can use the `key=` parameter for `max()` (like you'd use for `sorted()`, see below) to use `len(x)` for the key instead.

```py
>>> strings = ['enyky', 'benyky', 'yely','varennyky']
>>> sorted(strings)
['benyky', 'enyky', 'varennyky', 'yely']
>>> sorted(strings, key=len)
['yely', 'enyky', 'benyky', 'varennyky']
>>> max(strings, key=len)
'varennyky'
>>>
```